# K8S Azure Storage Account file share mount issue with ingress?

Tags: azure, docker, storage, kubernetes

have a Kubernetes cluster setup in Azure with AKS and I am running a simple apache deployment, for the purpose of this post httpd:2.4.

For assets storage I have a File Share mounted from an Azure Storage Account, this all seems to work but when serving slightly larger files, eg 3MB image, the connection closes with bytes left to read for some reason. This is not always the case, sometimes it serves the file fully and it only happens when serving files from the Azure Volume (serving large files from the local disk poses no issue)

Am I missing some configuration here or has anyone encountered a similar issue?

For reference is a rundown of my current configuration (Ingress, Deployment, PV, PVC) https://pastebin.com/gsnM9nP0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be an issue with `EnableSendFile` in Apache. Hard turning it off in the configuration solved the issue.